# Javascript request to SSL request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

For our APP we have a Web App and a API service, On A certain event the Web app polls the api service for the state of the event using Javascript. Both the apps run on a separate HTTPS sub domain and with a self signed certificate(as it is still in alpha). The problem occurs that the polling is aborted because the https api connection is untrusted. Is it some way for the Javascript request to override the untrusted certificate issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it some way for the Javascript request to override the untrusted certificate issue?

No, it's because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction.

In your case I suppose that you have a page hosted on `https://foo.bar.com` and you are trying to send an AJAX request to `https://baz.bar.com` which is not allowed.

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) which covers the different possibilities to circumvent this restriction. They range from JSONP, server side script bridges, Flash proxies,  screen scraping with YQL, ...

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to add the self-signed certificate to your machine/browser's trusted certificate store.

You also have cross-domain origin issues (the different subdomain), which is separate from any certificate issues.  If you're already using JSONP, you're fine; but if you're trying to make an XHR request to a different domain, it's not going to work.